# Subir una imagen a mi servidor con php y guardarla en una carpeta?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, imagen

Buenas como puedo subir una imagen desde carpeta local a una carpeta de mi servidor usando PHP. Logre hacer que se muestre en la base de datos con una columna llamada "image" pero no se sube a los archivos de mi servidor.

Me gustaría que las imágenes subidas a mi servidor se guarden en una carpeta llamada: /images/

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
<div class="form-group">
<br><label class="titulos">PORTADA</label><br>
<input type="file" name="image" class="img-upload"></select> <br>
</div>
```

.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    include "connection.php";
    $con  = connect();
    $sql = "insert into post (title,description,image,created_at) value (\"".$_POST["title"]."\",\"".$_POST["description"]."\",\"".$_POST["image"]."\",NOW())";
    $con->query($sql);
    $last_id = $con->insert_id;
    $categorias = get_categorias();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script para subir imágenes mediante un formulario y guardarlas en el servidor utilizando php.

Lo primero que tenemos que crear una página php incluyendo los tags html y dentro del body crear un formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
//Añadir imagen: 
<input name="archivo" id="archivo" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="subir" value="Subir imagen"/>
</form>
```

Este formulario tiene la acción de volver a cargar la página con método de envío POST y que va a permitir subir algún tipo de archivo. Contiene un input tipo file que nos permitirá seleccionar un archivo de nuestro disco duro y un botón tipo submit para ejecutar el formulario.

Al pulsar el botón «Subir imagen» será cuando entre en acción el código php que se encargará de comprobar y subir la imagen al servidor en el caso de que sea correcta. Este código pued ir en el mismo body por encima del formulario.

```
<?php
//Si se quiere subir una imagen
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
   //Recogemos el archivo enviado por el formulario
   $archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
   //Si el archivo contiene algo y es diferente de vacio
   if (isset($archivo) && $archivo != "") {
      //Obtenemos algunos datos necesarios sobre el archivo
      $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
      $tamano = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
      $temp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
      //Se comprueba si el archivo a cargar es correcto observando su extensión y tamaño
     if (!((strpos($tipo, "gif") || strpos($tipo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo, "jpg") || strpos($tipo, "png")) && ($tamano < 2000000))) {
        echo '<div><b>Error. La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta.<br/>
        - Se permiten archivos .gif, .jpg, .png. y de 200 kb como máximo.</b></div>';
     }
     else {
        //Si la imagen es correcta en tamaño y tipo
        //Se intenta subir al servidor
        if (move_uploaded_file($temp, 'images/'.$archivo)) {
            //Cambiamos los permisos del archivo a 777 para poder modificarlo posteriormente
            chmod('images/'.$archivo, 0777);
            //Mostramos el mensaje de que se ha subido co éxito
            echo '<div><b>Se ha subido correctamente la imagen.</b></div>';
            //Mostramos la imagen subida
            echo '<p><img src="images/'.$archivo.'"></p>';
        }
        else {
           //Si no se ha podido subir la imagen, mostramos un mensaje de error
           echo '<div><b>Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.</b></div>';
        }
      }
   }
}
?>
```

[Ver ejemplo en funcionamiento](https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/php/upload/index.php)

Fuente: https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/upload-de-imagenes-con-php/.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por responder pero no me funciona todavía. Ahora no se muestra en la columna de image y tampoco se sube al servidor

Comment: Añadí un comentario al código. Prueba de nuevo, por favor.

Comment: Gracias @BetaM !!

Comment: Pero no aparece la conexión hacia la base de datos, por eso no aparece en las columnas si no me equivoco.

Comment: Indicaste que eso lo lograste. Solo publique el código para subirlo en la carpeta images/  si deseas puede añadir el código de la BBDD y/o cambiar el nombre de la carpeta.

Comment: Oh cierto discúlpame lo que pasa es que soy nuevo en este mundo y estaba cometiendo un error en la linea de código, MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! me ayudaste un monton!!!.

Comment: Descuida, todos pasamos por esa alguna vez. Cualquier duda vuelve a preguntar. Seguro alguien responderá. Éxitos!